# How to determine if the digital signature field has been signed in xfa pdf?

Tags: javascript, ms-access, pdf, vba, adobe

Currently I can access all fields in my pdf created in Adobe livecycle except the signature field. I'm using the jso object in ms access to read the pdf "jso.xfa.resolvenode(path to field).formattedvalue()". I don't need the value of the digital signature, I just need to know if it's signed. When I access it now using the above reference it comes back empty,after it is signed. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks